# Creating two new corresponding rows for each unit of observation

Tags: r

I have a dataset with column male and female for each unit of observation. The dataset looks something like this.

| Country | Male_Value | Female_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 4 | 3 |

I need to create a dataset that looks like this.

| Country | Gender | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | male | 1 |
| A | female | 2 |
| B | male | 4 |
| B | female | 3 |

How do I get this output?

Here is the code for my example.

```
df<-data.frame(Country=c("A","B"), Male_value=c(1,4), Female_value=c(2,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Country, names_to = c('Gender', '.value'), 
           names_sep = '_')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Country Gender value
#  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
#1 A       Male       1
#2 A       Female     2
#3 B       Male       4
#4 B       Female     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this, however it is somehow similar to the one already posted:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(- Country, names_to = "Gender", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(Gender = str_to_title(Gender), 
         Gender = str_remove(Gender, "_value"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Country Gender value
  <chr>   <chr>  <dbl>
1 A       Male       1
2 A       Female     2
3 B       Male       4
4 B       Female     3
```